# Generate GWT class without using GWT.generate

Tags: java, gwt, generator

I have a series of models, each of which has some properties that are used by a generator to generate getters/setters automatically (because there is some logic relating to default values contained therein and I don't intend to write these manually for models with 20 odd fields).

When I'm instantiating the model, I use `GWT.create(...)`, but sometimes I have classes which refer to my model, and these don't know that the setters/getters exist, because they are generated.

For example, I have my model:

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractModel {
    private Integer uid;
    private String name;
    // ...
}

public interface JsonBinder<MyModel> {
    public void bindDataToMode(MyModel model, JSONWrapper json);
}
```

Now `JsonBinder<T>` is also a generated class using `GWT.create`, but it refers to `MyModel` and not the generated `MyModelImpl`. Therefore on compile I get errors like `setUid(Integer value) is not defined for class MyModel`.

Is there a way to have the compiler replace all uses of `MyModel` with `MyModelImpl`?

This applies to both generics and method arguments, return types, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In your specific case, I'd rather generate the `MyModelImpl` et al. upfront, using whichever code generator you want (including, for example, an annotation processor) and then code against the generated classes directly.

Comment: Ok thanks. That was going to be our alternative if we couldn't get the generators to work for this. Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the direction of details on how to generate code with annotations? I understand how to declare basic annotations that don't do anything (except "annotate") but is there a way of using them to generate code?

Comment: (I've found this: http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/) but if you have anything better then please do post it :)

Comment: Annotations don't allow me to modify my current source file it would seem, and the whole thing is rather messy, so I'm using Project Lombok.

Comment: Project Lombok is built on hacks (but works surprisingly well). The idea with annotation processors (or whichever the generator) is to have descriptors (in your case in the form of Java sources) that generate classes, but then your code only ever references the _generated_ classes. See https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Boilerplate-Generation for examples of that approach.

Comment: So is there no way to modify the current class with the annotation processors (in the same way Lombok does)?

Comment: AFAICT, unless you use the same hacks as Lombok (which BTW is an annotation processor), no. And they're really ugly hacks AFAIK.